# Random kernel panics after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kernel, crash

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 13.10 on my Samsung series 9 (NP900X3C). It was working great.

However after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, I'm getting random crashes and kernel panics. The system might run well for a whole day, but at other times the system crashes each hour.

The way a crash occurs isn't consistent. The system may freeze up, it can go black or I can get a kernel panic.

I often get a "Machine Check Exception" as shown below, but I've also had "not syncing" messages.

[image: Screenshot]

Please don't dismiss it as just faulty hardware. The laptop did not have this problem before upgrading and the kernel panics started almost right after the dist upgrade.